# SubSonic Tutorial?

Tags: subsonic

I have been looking and reading for an hour and i havent found a good tutorial for SubSonic. Do any of you have a recommendation?

I am looking for a quick command line or winform tutorial (not a asp.net tutorial) to take in a class and create the table, insert a few elements and query them again. I'll get to the advance things later (joins, etc. Or try to use linq?). I cant seem to find anything to tell me the namespace and object to do a query or insert. sure i see `var repo=new SimpleRepository(SimpleRepositoryOptions.RunMigrations);` but i am unsure what to do with it.

Answer (score 30):

The type of app shouldn't matter really - have you tried the screencasts/writeups at http://subsonicproject.com/docs? I really tried to put together as much as I could for people to get rolling.

Comment: Do you maintain the project/site? If so i can tell you exactly what i want to know and how i want it presented to me (its really quiet little). If you are email me and i'll send you some info.

Comment: I given up on subsonic. I'll use plain ado.net in a few days and write some helper extension methods.

Comment: I think that probably is the best option for you at this point.

Comment: I literally LOL'ed reading this little conversation. Just awesome.

Comment: Maybe Rob can write you a customized version of Subsonic also. lol

Comment: What is with these awful comments. I looked at it again today with a machine that had silverlight installed. I absolutely hate videos and was surprise there was no voice (i hate voice video tutorials). The 'Simple Repo 5 Minute Demo' alone told me more then 1hr of reading docs. I took 2 screenshots and thats all i needed. To bad that wasnt pasted in any of the docs. and too bad the example projects on site doesnt work on 3 installs of visual studios on different machines. All i was going to say was put an example to create a table with 1 insert and a select in one codefile.

Comment: I don't recall having any example projects on our site. If you'd like, I could come over and create your site for you while you read me Don Quixote - deal?

Comment: With regards to the "awful comments" - I think people are amused by your expectations with respect to something you don't have to pay for. I for one have enjoyed our conversation and I can't wait to find out what else you require to use my toolset.

Comment: i read my first comment again. I was saying was if you wanted i would have given you a list of my preference. I wasnt expecting anything. I wasn't asking for any or all to be done. It would have taken no more then 20 minutes to implement but obviously you dont want to hear it.

Comment: If I didn't want to hear about it I wouldn't be here friend. If you wouldn't mind taking that 20 minutes first it might be a good idea for you to think about what you're writing before you write it. You're telling me that I need to understand your preferences then spend more of time preparing content just for you. Hopefully you can see why I find that incredibly amusing, since I've spent 3 years creating this tool - I think you can spend a few minutes actually reading the content I've prepared.

Or not - you're always welcome to use ADO. In fact I would appreciate it if you did.

Comment: Haha i am starting to see the misunderstanding. Ok the first 2 suggestions are  1) Have one large code file that has the connection string inside (so no one needs to modify web.config) that users can run or copy/paste into their projects. and 2) offer video download links for people without silverlight. I hate videos so i didnt bother DLing silverlight. I thought most docs have the same info in video clearly explained in docs. After i got onto a machine with silverlight i watched the video and it was clear. All in 5 mins. Instead i spent 1.5 hour on documentation.

Comment: Bonus if you can do #1 with creating a database for the project in code. 3) would be nice if you have a comment mentioning not to forget to install the sqlite data provider. I never heard of installing anything for sqlite from anyone on SO or anywhere and had to ask a question why sqlite wasnt working. The first dev machine i tried subsonic on didnt have sqlexpress so knowing that would have been beneficial. I have a few more comments. Like i said they are 'really quiet little'. So many things went wrong when i read your docs.

Answer (score 3):

Google for [`repository pattern`](http://www.google.com/search?q=repository+pattern).

Basically - that's a class that abstracts persistence (simple CRUD functionality).

[learnsubsonic site](http://www.learnsubsonic.com/) might help too.

When i checked out subsonic - introduction videos worked great for me. Try them.